# what to do when the Special Price not the cheapest?

Tags: magento2, special-price

I have a Configurable Product and it has 3 Simple Products, one of them has a **Special Price** that is not the cheapest between them.

For Example :

The red colour cost 15 Euro and the Green colour (who has the Special price) costed now 16 Euro instead of 20 euro.

How to let Magento2 understand that is not always the cheapest Price is the Special Price ?

```
public function hasSpecialPrice()
{
    $displayRegularPrice = $this->getPriceType(Price\RegularPrice::PRICE_CODE)->getAmount()->getValue();
    $displayFinalPrice = $this->getPriceType(Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE)->getAmount()->getValue();
    return $displayFinalPrice < $displayRegularPrice;
}
```